# Using Forge Node.js SDK with 'Forge Design Automation v3'

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge

I am currently using the 'Forge Design Automation v3' in my project. I would like to know if it is possible to use the ‘Forge Node.js SDK’ and get rid of the error *“The 'Forge Design Automation v2' API is deprecated”*?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you are seeing is not an Error, it is a warning that we added to have customers aware of it. We will have this for a couple of months and remove it in the next update to the NPM.

Comment: Just changed the implementation to only display that message when someone uses the Design Automation v2 API - https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge.commandline-nodejs/issues/6 - please update to version 0.7.2